# How to get "Right Outer Join" like Diff in Git between 2 branches

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, `master` branch and a `dev` branch.

Like an usual scenario, `master` branch has latest changes that `dev` branch doesn't have, and `dev` branch was forked from `master` branch but at any given time got new commits to it without rebasing with the additional changes that got into the `master` branch since it was forked.

I am trying to find the difference in commits between `master` and `dev` branch in a way that it only shows me the new changes in the `dev` branch that went in since forked from `master`, but not the new changes in the `master` branch, which otherwise in a diff instruction shows up.

The closest thing I can relate this to is the Right Outer Join in a SQL query, where the new commits in the dev branch refers to the contents of the table whose contents are not available to the table it is compared with.

Have anyone ran into such requirement? Does anyone know how to get those diffs?

Comment: Can you not create a different branch from the latest commit at which point `dev` was created from `master` and compare this new branch with `dev` ?

Comment: basically `git checkout -b branchname <sha1-of-commit-at-point-of-fork>` then you can open PR from your `dev` branch to `branchname` to see the diff? Unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: that can be done manually, but the problem is that I am trying to perform this check in an automation. I cannot always reason about the state of ```dev``` branch compared to ````master``` branch and also places when ```dev``` may rebase with ```master``` it will create lot of hassles.

Comment: You can't really automate this. The manual method you mention *produces* the answer, which `git diff` can then *show as a diff*, but until you produce the answer, the answer isn't *there* so nothing can *show* it.

Comment: I think you're simply asking for either `git diff master...dev` or `git log master..dev`. Note there are 3 dots with diff and 2 dots for log, to isolate the right side branch only.

Comment: Hm, I may have misread the question as "looking to see what would happen if I selected particular commits, as if by cherry-picking" instead of "looking to see what would happen if I were to merge" (select *all* commits since the merge base). See the comment from @TTT above.